# Searching for a suitable layout to arrange my components in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jpanel

I am trying to develop a GUI using swing in Java.
I took a look at the different layouts but I wanted to know if there is some kind of layout that would allow multiple components in the centre of the screen one after the other because I noticed that if I use a border layout and place the components at the centre they over write each other. Is there a way to do this properly using any Layout?

I currently have a textarea and a button that I tried to add using a borderlayout in the center but  the text area is over written by the button and only the button displays.

```
    fPanel.add(text1TextArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    fPanel.add(button1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

It would be really helpful if someone could link examples.

Comment: By "one after the other" do you man horizontally or vertically?

Comment: GridBagLayout is the most flexible single layout, however, when you're building complex UIs in Swing, you need to learn to nest layouts one (or more) within the other. Don't limit your thinking.

Comment: You're not stuck to using a single layout.  You can use "compound" layouts to produce complex UIs (ie placing components in seperate containers using different layouts)

Comment: @Mihe Vertically.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Okaay!

Comment: @MadProgrammer True! I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public void run() {
        JPanel content = createSomeContent();
        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        center.add(content);
                
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(center);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createSomeContent() {
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout vBox = new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        content.setLayout(vBox);
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.BLACK));
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Input:");
        JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        
        content.add(label);
        content.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));     
        content.add(input);
        content.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        content.add(button);
        return content;
    }    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test().run());
    }
}
```